# Eclipse Galileo, Plugin Install

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.5

is this last week, I installed Eclipse IDE version 3.5 (helios) has since spent time setting up in my favor .. I needed to download some plugins, to be more specific the UML2Tools, and came across the following message 'File Transport Reader has encountered a problem', I looked in various places for various solutions to this, and no enough, I made the change of 'Network Connections' to Manual .. Native .. I tried to install the plugin manually moving files to the folder dropins or sending the data folders of features / plugins to the folder features / plugins eclipse .. nothing .. someone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you installed 3.5?  That version is over two years old.  The current version is 3.7.

You are probably getting that error because one of the update sites is corrupted.  Your best bet is to move to 3.7 and use the more recent update sites.  If you can't do that, then you should contact the project team responsible for the update site so they can fix it.

Comment: Hello, yeah, but I can not install on other versions UML2Tools .. far as I know, only works on Galileo .. or am I wrong?

Comment: It looks like there are a bunch of update sites here: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/downloads/?project=uml2  I am not sure how active this project is, but you can try downloading the all-in-one update site and pointing your update manager to the zip (no need to unzip it).

Comment: I think I managed to solve .. making the MDT update, then the own list of available packages, the UML had 2 Tools, version 0.8.1 .. was the only one compatible with my eclipse, thanks for the help, and even more .. whatever, come back to comment on this issue!

Comment: Opz, I was wrong .. problem in 28% gave the same error mentioned in the question .. finally .. I can not install manually, you have a tutorial teaching how to manually install plugins in eclipse? seje perhaps my only attempt ..